# Reduce padding between captions and tables

Tags: r, r-markdown, flextable

I'm using flextable to loop over a list of data, generating captions and tables for each element in the list to generate tables in an `rmarkdown` document. While I can successfully render the captions and tables, the padding/margins between captions and tables is too large, and I can't find a way to reduce them. Here's what I have so far:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
date: '2022-05-09'
---

``{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flextable)
library(magrittr)
``

``{r results='asis', echo=FALSE, ft.align="left"}

my_list<-list()
my_list$ds1<-head(mtcars, 5)
my_list$ds2<-head(mtcars, 10)

for (i in 1:length(my_list)) {
  
  myft <- flextable(my_list[[i]]) %>% 
    set_caption(paste("Caption ", i))
  
  flextable_to_rmd(myft)
  
}
``
```

I thought that perhaps using `flextable::padding()` would help, but this seems to only control the padding within the table rows, rather than the spacing between elements on a page.

Note that I've removed some of the required markdown backticks in the code sample above so that it can render correctly on Stackoverflow.

[image: Unwanted padding between caption and top of the table]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your RMD. Don't put it in a code chunk—just place it where you might otherwise free-write.

```
<style>
caption {
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
</style>
```

Right now the caption is written in p tags, surrounded by caption tags, surrounded by more p tags, all of which have padding, margin, and line-height specs. This gives you the biggest bang for the least effort (IMO).

[image]